# Python long list is broken into annoying multiple line in VScode?

Tags: python, list, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXkxA.png)

Hi, I am using VScode for python. I face an annoying point in autoformat that a long list is broken into multiple lines as shown in the picture. I try to change wordwrap property but it does not help.

Comment: Which format are you using? Could you please provide us with the content of your "settings.json" file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the Python formatting toolkit "`autopep8`", and its effects are as follows:

[image]

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
```

It is recommended that you check whether there are related settings in the file "settings.json" that affect the use of formatting.

The "autopep8" in VSCode is used as the formatting code of the Python formatting toolkit. We can use it by installing it using pip. Please disable related formatting extensions to avoid interference.

More references: [Formatting in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatterspecific-settings).

Comment: I used the same to you: autopep8, but the behavior in my vscode is so weird when I format the code.

Comment: This is my code:
    `"editor.fontSize": 17,`
    `"editor.fontWeight": "400",`
    `"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",`
    `"editor.formatOnSave": true,`
    `"code-runner.executorMap": {`
        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",`
        "perl": "perl"`
    `},`
    `"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,`
    `"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false`

Comment: @Trong Nhan Nguyen -The results of my test using the settings you provided are still the same as my answer. Have you installed the VSCode extension of the relevant formatting code? It is recommended that you reinstall and use "[autopep8](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting)".

Comment: I just switched to VS code from sublime text 2 days ago. So I only install basic extension like python, code-runner, autopep8, black or yaf.

Comment: @Trong Nhan Nguyen -The "autopep8" in VSCode is used as the formatting code of the Python formatting toolkit. We can use it by installing it using pip. Please disable extensions such as "autopep8, black or yaf" to avoid their interference.

Answer (score 0):

Save without Formatting is done by

1: Press CTRL + K then

2 : Press CTRL + Shift + S

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the type of formatter you use in vscode. If you use ctrl+shift+p and select user settings. Then search for format and scroll down on left in the extensions, you'll see python. Now you should be able to change your default formatter. Also to avoid format on save, uncheck "Editor: Format On Save"